# Device writable even after `blockdev --setro`

Tags: block-device, readonly

I want to use the functionality of `umount -l`, then remove the underlying device as safely as possible afterward.

- I can't use `umount --force` to unmount the filesystem as it has become invisible to new processes.
- I can't use `lsof` for an accurate list of the open files as the filesystem has become invisible to new processes.
- If I use `lsof` before `umount -l`, there is a race contition of a new file being opened in between the two invocations.

I'm testing a work-around: `sync && blockdev --setro /dev/<device>`

The manual for `blockdev --setro` only says:

> Set read-only.

Is the man page missing something? This seems to create a file on a `--setro` device:

```
# mount /dev/loop0 mountpoint/
# blockdev --setro /dev/loop0
# echo test > mountpoint/f
# sync
# umount mountpoint
# mount /dev/loop0 mountpoint/
mount: /tmp/mountpoint: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.
# cat mountpoint/f
test
#
```

Environment:

```
$ uname -a
Linux svelte 4.9.39-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 21 08:25:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ blockdev --version
blockdev from util-linux 2.30
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess `blockdev --setro` works similar to `chmod`: It affects only future openings of the object.

But I can offer a work-around for your detection problem:

1. The `/proc/$PID/cwd` value is changed to `/` after the lazy unmount.
2. The paths of open files of the process shown in `/proc/$PID/fd` are moved up to `/`, e.g. `/mnt/tmp/output` becomes `/output`.

So you can first filter all processes with cmd `/`. There may be false positives among them but this is very fast. The next step (not necessarily complete but probably faster) is to check `/proc/$PID/fd` of all these processes for files which do not exist at their shown paths.

The complete but probably not so fast check is to run `stat` for all files in `/proc/$PID/fd`. It shows the original device. So you might check this value before the umount to make things easier.

Comment: Thanks for the work-around idea. I've raised [`blockdev`: Document that `--setro` only applies to new access #498](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/issues/498) to have the full behaviour documented.